# Using SendMessage() to minimize all windows, but need a more efficient way than Thread.Sleep() to wait until the legacy desktop is showing

Tags: c#

In my C# console application, I am using `SendMessage()` to minimize all windows, effectively showing the Windows 8 Legacy Desktop.  This works great, but I have to use a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in order to wait for the Legacy Desktop to actually show before before I try to do anything else.

```
IntPtr lHwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

I really want to replace the `Thread.Sleep()` with a more efficient way to detect that the Legacy Desktop is showing before continuing on.

Any ideas?

Edit:
Here are the Interop wrappers and constants.  just in case it helps..

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
const int MIN_ALL = 419;
const int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 416;
```

Comment: How do you know that in the time that you are waiting for the desktop to be shown, the user hasn't un-minimized one of the windows? What is the real problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps there is a more reliable way to achieve that.

Comment: I'm trying to minimize all windows, then launch a specific legacy desktop program on the next line.  I'm assuming the system has not been touched for some time, and I am just trying to reset the computer to show a program.  Using SendMessage() the way I do even minimizes to legacy desktop even if the computer is currently showing any Start Screen apps...  but some time is needed between SendMessage() and actually launching the program I want.

Comment: Always make sure that your uninstaller is flawless when you write code like this.  It will be the most often used feature of your program.

Comment: Why can't you just launch the program? Why do you have to minimize all open windows first?

Comment: If Windows 8 Start Screen is currently the foreground window, you cant lauch a Legacy Desktop app and expect it to show.  It /will/ launch, but it /will not/ show.

Comment: You can't run this code from a metro app anyway, so I'm not really sure why that's a problem.

Comment: Im running a console app

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work any better for you, but perhaps it's worth a try...

(1) Add to your project a reference to "Shell32" (via Add Reference -> COM -> Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation).

(2) Set the reference's "Embed Interop Types" to `false`.

(3) Use the following code to minimise all the windows:

```
dynamic shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
shell.MinimizeAll();
```

However, I suspect that this is just an alternative way of doing the SendMessage().

Comment: I tried what you said and there was no difference.  I do appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @user1190320 I feared as much. :(